# Simple php mail function doesn't succed for a given webmail address

Tags: php, email

I have a simple PHP script in the root of my client's website:

```
<?php  
      $to = "info@xxxxxxxxxx.it"; 
      $header = "From: {$to}";
      $subject = "Hi!"; $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?"; 
      if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)) 
      { 
          echo("<p>ok</p>"); 
      } 
      else { 
          echo ("<p>no invio</p>"); 
      } 
      echo '<br/>'; 
?>
```

The fact is that when I test my own email addresses (ex. GMail) it works otherwise if I test with my client's Webmail it fails.

Comment: check your mail server's logs. most likely the email is getting treated as spam. mail() is garbage and should be avoided. use a proper mail package, such as PHPMailer or Swiftmailer.

Comment: "It fails" can mean everything. How does it fail?

Comment: the "simple" php `mail()` function is a pile of croc. use [phpMailer class](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/) instead.

Comment: @GolezTrol - part of the problem with php's mail func is that very often it doesn't tell you what failed.

Comment: Sure, but it does tell you if it failed or if it think it succeeded. A mail that failed to arrive may very well have successfully left the sender.

Answer (score 0):

@user you must add "Reply-to:" if you send to gmail, yahoo,etc..

Answer (score 0):

You have `$to` inside from.

```
 $to = "info@xxxxxxxxxx.it"; 
 $header = "From: {$to}";
```

I think, that's reason why only you recieve it.

You shold define `$from` in same way and then change header.

```
 $header = "From: {$from}";
```

There is enough examples on https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

It's basically in this part:

```
$header = "From: {$to}";
```

Setting a `From:` header nowadays is bad practice unless the domain is owned by yourself, because most mail systems will reject emails that aren't sent from a legitimate server.

It's better to leave the `From:` alone and use `Reply-To:` instead.

For example, if you add `"From: xxx@gmail.com"` to the mail headers, the servers at Google will check whether your server is authorized to send email on behalf of gmail users. They do this, amongst others, by checking the [SPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) records for that email domain.